# some issues about NodeJs 's module "Passport"

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

Any one who can show a example of using passportJS that not depend on Open Id(facebook,twitter,google etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on their website.

To use a `local` authentication strategy check out their [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/).

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

The example assumes you have a database in your app to check users and passwords against.

Working examples are in the `passport-local` repo [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples)